# Adjusting graphs with Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm having some problems adjusting the font size of the numerical labels on y axis of my graphs. Adjusting the font size only seems to adjust the text in the legend box.

Adjusting the 'axes' doesn't work because I've used `axes.ravel()` to help give a 2x2 set of four subplots.

> "axes.set_xlabel(fontsize='large', fontweight='bold') AttributeError:
>   'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'"

```
#The part of the code that creates the subplots.

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(40,20), squeeze=False, sharey=True)
axes = axes.ravel()

font = FontProperties()

font = {'weight' : 'bold','size'   : 22}

plt.rc('font', **font)

#Then under here are the loops that create each subplot.

for each_subplot in range(0,4):

    axes.set_xlabel(fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')

#Selecting the input data goes here, but I left it out.
```

Answer (score 2):

`axes` itself is an array of axes. So you want to do:

```
for each_subplot in range(0,4):
    axes[each_subplot].set_xlabel(fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
```

or simpler:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xlabel(fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
```

Comment: I think I have worked out part of my problem, I want to be making the numbers on the scale of the y axis have a larger font, which I think is different to axes.set_ylabel(). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`axes` is an ndarray now, so you need to extract the element from array and call `set_xlabel()` method on it. Try this.

```
for each_subplot in range(0,4):
    axes[each_subplot].set_xlabel(fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
```

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, I would personally recommend using `enumerate` which provides you access not only to the individual axis objects but also to the index which can be used to modify labels, for instance. To flatten the `axes`, you can either use `axes.ravel()` or `axes.flatten()`. Also, you can directly use `axes.flatten()` in the `enumerate` as shown below.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8,5), squeeze=False, sharey=True)

for index, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()):
    ax.set_xlabel('X-label %s' %index, fontsize='large', fontweight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]